# Mocking callback ref in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that renders a third party component. When rendering, it stores this component's ref locally in `localApi`. When the button is clicked it calls the `exportData` function which returns some data in a callback.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    let localApi = React.useRef() as any;

    const submit = () => {
        localApi.exportData((data) => {
            // do something with data
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ThirdParty ref={(api) => localApi = api} fullVersion={true}/>
            <button onSubmit={submit}>Submit</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem I'm facing is mocking this ThirdParty component's ref in Jest. Since my mock isn't working, upon simulating a clickon the button throws `exportData is not defined` error. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
jest.mock("third-party", () => ({
    default: (props: any) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
        const React = require("react");

        console.log(props); // this only returns the `fullVersion = true` when 

        const MockThirdParty: React.FC = () => {
            const exportData = (callBack) => {
                callBack("Mock data");
            }

            return <div>Third Party Component</div>;
        }

        return <MockThirdParty/>;
    },
    __esModule: true,
}));
```

How can I go about mocking it properly?

Comment: what is third-party module? is it from npm?

Comment: Yes it is from npm

Comment: is it this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/third-party can't see react component in this library.

Comment: ThirdParty is not an actual component. I just named it that since it could be any third party component.

Comment: with react testing library it not recommended to mock most of things while writing integration tests. so your third party module should be giving you some api. if you can give some details what is failing then it will be easy to help.